# Mount LVM2 and recover lost data from failed HDD?

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, putty, lvm

HDD failure occurred.

So, a new primary HDD was added in and the old HDD was added in as a secondary one.

I'm trying to mount my secondary HDD but there are errors occurring.

I made `/media/qwe/`.

I then went on Putty and used these SSH commands:

```
root@chicken [/]# mount /dev/sdb2 /media/qwe
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

But, I got an error.

[image: vgdisplay]

```
root@chicken [/]# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "VolGroup" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "VolGroup" using metadata type lvm2


root@chicken [/]# vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  VolGroup   1   3   0 wz--n- 1.82t    0
  VolGroup   1   3   0 wz--n- 1.82t    0
```

[image: vgchange -a y]

I use cPanel and WHM.

I am trying to recover the MySQL databases that were lost. I managed to mount the sdb1 bit, but I think that's the boot partition. I don't need that. I need to access the other files!

Any help?

Comment: What's the type of tables , myisam or Innodb ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a programming question.  You should try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) and/or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I can't even access it. I don't know what kind of tables they are.

I'm a total noob. I am stressing out because I lost very valuable MySQL databases that I can't retrieve.

The HDD is attached, so why can't I mount it? I don't know why it is so hard for me to mount it, it almost feels impossible. Can an expert enlighten me?

Comment: Is it a problem that they share the same volume group name?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need file system to get you data back. 
Start with [taking an image from the failed disk](https://twindb.com/take-image-from-corrupted-hard-drive/)

Comment: Thanks. Would I just be able to use 7zip to extract that after downloading it? It sounds like a great idea.

Comment: dd if=/dev/sdb of=/path/on/sda/faulty_disk.img  conv=noerror

What's this? /path/on/sda/ 

I've never seen "/path/on/" before. Could I change it to "/faulty_disk.img" instead by removing the "/path/on/sda/" bit?

Comment: I'm not familiar with 7zip. You should take an image from the disk because if the disk fails any next read operation may be unsuccessful. After the image is ready you can think on recovery plan. Depending on MySQL table types(MyISAM or InnoDB) you may want to use different tools. My point was don't bother yourself with file systems, most probably it's not recoverable. But you don't need it, you need the data

Comment: "What's this? /path/on/sda/ I've never seen "/path/on/" before", - hmm, I should have been more clear. Save the image in any directory. Just make sure it's on a good disk.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm doing it now. I wonder how long it will take. It's taking a while.

Comment: It's unpredictable because depends on the amount of faulty blocks. A read from the faulty block may take seconds

Comment: `dd: opening `/path/on/sda/faulty_disk.img': No such file or directory
root@rpg134591 [~]# dd if=/dev/sdb of=/faulty_disk.img  conv=noerror
dd: writing to `/faulty_disk.img': No space left on device
87273425+0 records in
87273424+0 records out
44683993088 bytes (45 GB) copied, 1786.46 s, 25.0 MB/s`

What does it mean no space left on device?

Comment: File size is too big. Is there a different way? I just want to copy a specific part of it?

Can't I explore it with SFTP or something?